# Tongue exercises relaxation (Flap T/D)

Tags: pronunciation, english

I have a question about pronunciation. I've been studying English practically for my whole life, but for some reason I have such a hard time pronouncing the **FLAP T**. I do know how to make it perfectly, but whenever I try to pronounce it it sounds really forced and whenever I try to talk fast like if I want to say *"It was such a pretty day"*, the *'pretty'* word comes up I get so stucked!

Don't even get me started on pronouncing words like *turtle, murder*, or saying *order to*. I don't know. I used to practice English like crazy when I was a kid and a teenager and even in adulthood, making the **flap T**, would be extremely easy, been practicing 3 hours daily for over 5 months with words like *murder, turtle* and listening to native speakers saying it and repeating it with them".

Still, CAN'T pronounce it properly and fluently. **Why? What exercises can help me improving it?** Do I need to focus on "tongue exercises"? Jaw exercises, too?

Comment: If tongue exercises are what you are looking for, I can definitely give you a few recommendations, since I have also done such exercises. If you want more specific advice, it would be good to have a sample recording, like in the question [How can I improve my accent?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/3808/800)

Comment: Can you please add which variant of English you are using or learning? American English, British English, ...?